# python unable to get dictionary from string

Tags: python, dictionary, encoding, subprocess

I have a subprocess that prints a string that I would like to use as a dictionary.

```
b"{'name': 'Bobby', 'age': 141}\r\n"
```

I am decoding the output using.

```
d = p.stdout.read().decode("utf-8").strip()
```

Why am I unable to use it as a dictionary? `d['name']` returns `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Does anyone know what is going on? Is it some kind of encoding issue?

Cheers,
Chris

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the inbuilt `json` module; speficially, `json.loads()`.

`json.loads()` inputs a string/text object and returns a Python dictionary. JSON's syntax uses double quotes for keys and values, however, so you'd need to reformat your string to use double quotes instead of single quotes:

```py
'{"name": "Bobby", "age": 141}\r\n'
```

Then we can use the `json` module:

```py
import json

my_string = '{"name": "Bobby", "age": 141}\r\n'
my_dic = json.loads(my_string)
print(my_dic, type(my_dic))
```

Which will result:

```
{'name': 'Bobby', 'age': 141} <class 'dict'>
```

Comment: Thank you. That didn't work because even when I had the subprocess script print with double quotes it was still showing single. I had to use `.replace` to replace them. It is working now, thanks.